# Sort int in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I want to sort a column with int in it in a JTable. I use `TableRowSorter` with the sort order `SortOrder.ASCENDING`. But somehow it sorts not how I actually want it.

What I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

What is the Problem? And how can I fix it?

Here is the SSCCE:

**`ResultGUI.java`**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ResultGUI {

    protected static JTable ranglisteTable = new JTable();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 368, 316);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        //MODEL
        Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();     
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
        row.addElement(3);      
        data.addElement(row);
        Vector<Object> row2 = new Vector<Object>();
        row2.addElement(2);     
        data.addElement(row2);
        Vector<Object> row3 = new Vector<Object>();
        row3.addElement(1);     
        data.addElement(row3);
        Vector<Object> row4 = new Vector<Object>();
        row4.addElement(22);        
        data.addElement(row4);
        Vector<Object> row5 = new Vector<Object>();
        row5.addElement(13);        
        data.addElement(row5);              
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        columnNames.addElement("Points");   
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            ranglisteTable.setRowHeight(i, 30);
        }

        ranglisteTable.setBounds(109, 0, 128, 277);
        ranglisteTable.setModel(model);

        //SORTING
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(ranglisteTable.getModel());        
        ranglisteTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
        List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        sorter.sort();

        frame.add(ranglisteTable);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you try this code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;

public class ResultGUI extends JFrame
{
    public ResultGUI()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"points"};
        Object[][] data =
        {{ new Long(1)}, { new Long(2)},{ new Long(9) },{ new Long(4)}
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {

            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                // Lookup first non-null data on column
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) 
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null)
                        return o.getClass();
                }

                return Object.class;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        // DefaultRowSorter has the sort() method
        DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter()); 
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add( new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING) );
        sorter.setSortKeys(list);
        sorter.sort();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ResultGUI frame = new ResultGUI();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at this http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/6-techniques-for-sorting-jtable-you-should-know

Comment: @Holger  i changed my take a look at it. please

Answer (score 3):

Try this override the getColumnClass method in DefaultTableModel:

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) return Integer.class;
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    };
```

If you don't override, JTable treats the first columns as Object instead of Integer. Now, it should sort based on the integer values.

Comment: This only works if I have 1 element in a row. But I got the answer thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your table simply doesn’t know that your data contains numbers and `DefaultTableModel` reports every column type as `Object`. But in the end, your usage of `DefaultTableModel` isn’t simpler than implementing your own table model. Just replace everything between `//MODEL` and `TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);` with:

```
    //MODEL
    final int[] data={ 3, 2, 1, 22, 13, };
    TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if(columnIndex!=0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            return data[rowIndex];
        }
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            if(column!=0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            return "Points";
        }
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    };
```

Now that `getColumnClass` reports `Integer.class` instead of `Object.class` for your sole column, it will get sorted correctly.